# Vertically center content of a floated div with an unfixed height

Tags: html, css

I have a set of divs within a slider that are floated. and within these divs I would like to vertically center content, mainly text. I tried something like this but it doesn't work:

```
<div class="floated">
  <div class="table">
     <div class"table-cell">
         <p>text</p>
     </div>
 </div>
</div>

.floated{
  float:left;
}

.table{
  display:table;
  vertical-align:middle;
  height:100%;
}

.table-cell{
   display:table-cell;

}
```

IMPORTANT: I can't set the height of any parent elements!

Comment: `class"table-cell">` should be `class="table-cell">`

Answer (score 1):

```css
.floated { float:left; }
.table { display:table; height:100%; }
.table-cell { display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle; }
```

```html
<div class="floated">
  <div class="table">
     <div class="table-cell">
         <p>text</p>
     </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

vertical-align is on table-cell not table

Answer (score 0):

you missed "=" at this line `<div class"table-cell">`

Answer (score 0):

your div has a typo and try adding a margin to your table display

```
 <div class="floated">
      <div class="table">
         <div class="table-cell">
             <p>text</p>
         </div>
     </div>
    </div>

    .floated{
      float:left;
    }

    .table{
      display:table;
      vertical-align:middle;
      height:100%;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }

    .table-cell{
       display:table-cell;
    }
```